# How to get exit status of spark-shell<<EOF <spark queries>EOF in bash script?

Tags: bash, spark-shell

I have part of shell script as below..

spark_data=`spark-shell << EOF spark.sql(query) EOF`

i need the exit status of the spark.sql query..
Can someone help on this..

Awaiting your reply
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since the assignment is part of another command, the exit status of the assignment is the exit status of the command substitution.

```
$ foo=$(cat <<EOF
> hi
> there
> EOF
> exit 9)
$ echo $?
9
$ echo "$foo"
hi
there
```

Comment: The above strategy will not work with herein EOF. Can anyone try and answer oks

Comment: Sure it does; you just can't put it all on one line (which is true no matter where you use a here document).

Comment: In the above eg you used exit 9 after EOF..But in my case I have Scala language commands in the place of 'Hi there '..what i need is spark-shell exit status..in you example it's cat command exit status

Comment: I need the exact exit status of those Scala commands in spark-shell...like exit 0 so that I need to know the success or failure of those  commands inside EOF.........HERE spark-shell is like your cat Scala commands are like hi there..I want exit status of spark-shell as your cat in the eg..

Comment: I already check with your strategy but it dint work for me..

Comment: As cat command is internal to Unix it gave the exit status correctly in your case I think

Comment: `cat` is no more internal than `spark-shell`. It has nothing to do with the shell. It's only there to provide output to be assigned to `foo`. The exit status of the command substitution is 9, and that's the exit status of the assignment itself. The Scala commands don't *have* an exit status, at least not in the sense that the shell can access.

Comment: So how can we get the exit status of spark-shell success or failure? I tried like below by giving va x instead of val x but dint work..spark-shell <<eof va x=1;eof exit $?.....and after that when i do echo $? it's always giving zero instead of nonzero number..I want exact exit Status of spark-shell??